# can't get node-ffi module working

Tags: node-ffi

just for testing purposes I created a small DLL in delphi. The code being:

```
library MyDll;
uses
    SysUtils,
    Classes,
    Vcl.Dialogs;
function DllMessage(const echo: string): string;  export;
begin
    //ShowMessage('Hello world from a Delphi DLL') ;
    Result := 'Echo:  ' + echo;
end;
exports DllMessage;
begin
end
```

I just want to run something as simple as this with this nodejs code:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
console.log("1");
var mylib = ffi.Library('MyDll', {'DllMessage': [ 'string', [ 'string' ] ] });
console.log(2");
var outstring = mylib.DllMessage('abc');
console.log("3" + outstring);
```

problem is that I see "1" and "2" on the console and nothing else.
Please help, any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Pass your string data as buffer

```
var message = Buffer.from('abc')
var outstring = mylib.DllMessage(message);
console.log("3" + outstring);
```